# CRON job to update wp_usermeta value each day or week based on server time

Tags: php, wp-cron, cron

My Wordpress site has a registration field that asks members how many weeks pregnant they are.

If a member insert `5` then 7 days later that integer needs to increase to `6`.

Pseudo code for what I want is:

```
If mysite_user_weekspregnant > 0
   get current_day++

   case current_day => 1 and <= 7
      set week 1
   case current_day > 7 and <= 14
      set week 2
   ...
   ...
   case current_day > 273 and <= 270
      set week 40
```

`mysite_user_weekspregnant` is stored within table: `wp_usermeta`.

How do I turn this into a CRON job?

Comment: Does this really need to be updated in the database? If you have the registration date and the number of weeks pregnant they were at that time, you can calculate this at runtime. No need to keep updating the database, because you already have the information you need.

Comment: In a typical use case that would make sense but I am actually pre-registering these participants (sometimes a month ahead of their initial log in).  So the date they provide their "weeks pregnant" is not the same date they register

Comment: It doesn't have to be the "registration" date. I just mean that you presumably know the date that they provided this number, which is all you need. If you don't have that date then doing it by cron is also going to be inaccurate.

Comment: Asking them for, or calculating, their due date would let you store a single value. You could use that due date to trigger whatever other things you want, such as calculating how many weeks pregnant they are to show different content, etc.

Comment: @WebElaine much better idea - and that's how I implemented it. Thanks